# How to improve weak Bluetooth signal on a Linux laptop?

Tags: linux, laptop, bluetooth

I'm using Linux KDE Neon on a Dell laptop. There is a software issue that is causing the Bluetooth signal to be drastically weaker than it is supposed to be. I know that, because I used to be able to walk away (inside a single room, around seven meters) from my laptop with Bluetooth headphones without issues. Now, the same headphones can not connect when within 1.5 meters (5 feet) of the laptop. When connected, the sound cuts out when the distance increases above one meter (3 feet). These headphones are the only device connected to the laptop over Bluetooth.

- **Linux Laptop Issue**: I know that this is an issue on the Linux laptop, because I tested the same headphones with other Bluetooth devices in the same room: a different PC with a Bluetooth dongle, a MacBook, and two different Android phones. All of them connect and work without audio cutting out in 5-7 meters range.
- **Weak Signal**: I know that this is a weak signal issue, because the headphones connect to the laptop and work normally when I move them within 30 cm (one foot) of the laptop.
- **Software Issue**: I know that this is a software issue, because recently after some combination of different invocations of `bluetoothctl`, `rfkill`, and `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` the issue went away. Unfortunately, the issue came back when I rebooted the OS, and I haven't been able to reproduce this workaround since.
- WiFi is turned off on this laptop.

In my usual physical setup, `hcitool rssi ...` returns values between `-63` and `-66`. `hcitool lq` almost always returns `255`. (from [this answer on the Linux and Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393497/53143))

Is there any way in Linux to boost the Bluetooth signal strength from software without additional hardware?

Could this be a bug in my configuration? Could this be a bug in BlueZ? Linux kernel?

Also, after observing this for some time, it seems that there is another symptom. Bluetooth signal is fine when the audio is continuous. That is, if I'm far enough from the laptop, then as soon as a song or video end, the Bluetooth headphones are disconnected. Can Pulseaudio affect Bluetooth connections like that?

Comment: As a workaround, I wrote a Bash script which checks the connection and reconnects, if needed https://github.com/rybak/scripts/blob/master/bluetooth/keep-bt.sh

Answer (score 3):

#### 2023-03-31 update

After multiple unsuccessful attempts yesterday, I seem to have finally found a "one step" solution: cycle the laptop through sleep.

#### 2023-03-30 update

It's gotten much worse. Now none of the things that randomly fixed it before work.

I've found https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset, but none of the suggestions there are relevant. Section "Connecting works, but there are sound glitches all the time" sounds promising, but it is not what I am experiencing. The sound is perfect, but only when I put my head right next to the laptop.

#### 2023-01-06 update

I still don't understand what's going on. The issue came back very shortly after New Year's Eve update. I am very much [cargo-culting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) my way through `bluetoothctl`, `btmon`, `modprobe`, turning Bluetooth on and off in BIOS, etc. to get the software side of the Bluetooth stack to cooperate, but at least after a week of suffering, I can use my headphones normally again. That is, I am trying random things without understanding which of the exact combination of them has helped.

For the record, the list this time is:

1. Disable/enable Bluetooth from desktop environment controls (KDE).
2. Disconnect/Connect headphones a couple of times.
3. Turn headphones on and off.
4. Cycle through noise cancelling settings of the headphones just to see if `btmon` "sees" any effect from different noise cancelling modes.
5. Reboot to change BIOS settings – disable Bluetooth in BIOS.
6. Reboot to DE, double check that Bluetooth is indeed disabled.
7. Reboot to change BIOS settings – enable Bluetooth back in BIOS.
8. Reboot, check audio – audio still cuts out.
9. Reboot again and cycle headphones on/off again.
10. Use `bluetoothctl` to disconnect and connect instead of DE controls.
11. Use the `modprobe` command that helped me with some WiFi issues in the past:

    ```
    sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
    sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
    ```

This is very disheartening, but at least it's a relief from the hard-to-describe visceral discomfort from sound cutting out in the most annoying timing possible after, for example, just turning the head.

##### Side note

On my laptop `btmon` (for the record, found about it from [a random bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212387) that turned up when typing "linux bluetooth Sony WH-1000MX3" into a search engine) is much better for the purposes of keeping track of Bluetooth signal than `hcitool rssi` I mentioned in the question above. Basically, when signal is good (from perceived audio quality point of view), I can see big packets (at least it seems to be a packet, I don't actually know), about 50-55 lines long in the terminal, presumably being sent to the headphones. But when the signal cuts out, `btmon` output either stops dead, or the packets suddenly become much smaller, 20-25 lines long, as if the laptop is trying a lower bitrate to keep the signal going at all cost.

#### 2022-12-31 update

And suddenly, just two days later, the bluetooth is working fine again! The only thing remotely connected to this is that the laptop went through a sleep-wake cycle.

#### 2022-12-29 update

Yep, the problem is definitely in software. After another `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, with no other changes, the bluetooth signal is bad again. When laptop lid is closed, it's barely 1.5 meters. When lid is open, it's about 3 meters. And a reboot didn't help.

#### 2022-03-11 update

Today I remembered about this question. I don't know what changed, but after some testing I don't appear to have any signal strength issues anymore, both with open and closed laptop lid. Since May 2021, the laptop got an upgrade (unrelated to Bluetooth), during which its insides were cleaned – only minor dusting, nothing that should interfere with the signal. If it was a software issue, my current combination of Linux kernel and `bluez` package doesn't have it:

```
$ uname -svrpi
Linux 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64
$ apt show bluez 2>/dev/null | head -2 
Package: bluez
Version: 5.53-0ubuntu3.5
```

#### Old answer

The solution to my problem is: **open the laptop lid**. I'm using external monitor, keyboard, and mouse. The laptop lid is almost always closed. However, when the lid is opened, there are no Bluetooth issues which were described in the question.

I guess that when I got Bluetooth to work:

> - **Software Issue**: I know that this is a software issue, because recently after some combination of different invocations of `bluetoothctl`, `rfkill`, and `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` the issue went away. Unfortunately, the issue came back when I rebooted the OS, and I haven't been able to reproduce this workaround since.

the laptop was opened just by accident.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I have the same problem, now as your last update said, It could be the problem of antenna.

Comment: @walknotes keep in mind – the last update with the newest information is at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can not leave a comment to another answer, but I found the same issue on my archlinux. My solution was to downgrade linux kernel:
6.4.12.zen1-1 -> 6.3.9.zen1-1

So on kernel linux 6.3.9.zen1-1 the bluetooth is working perfectly, but using kernel linux 6.4.12.zen1-1 or fresher I noticed that signal is lots of weaker.
I also found that it is working not so bad at home, where I'm using wired mouse and keyboard, but it is working a lot worse on work where I'm using wireless devices (but with old kernel headphones are working good in both places!).

So my conclusion is there is software issue which is related to weak signal which is interfering with other bluetooth devices.

Update:
my bluetooth adapter is `USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B85C="Realtek Wireless Bluetooth Adapter"`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my laptop, it started after some software upgrade. The connection almost always becomes unstable if I'm more than 1 meter away from the laptop, sometimes the Bluetooth headphones struggle to connect to the laptop, Bluetooth Monitor shows poor Link Quality, and the sound intermittently cuts out. Although sometimes the connection remains stable even at 3 meters distance.

It might be a bug in the kernel driver for the built-in Bluetooth card (I have Intel AX201). Today I disabled the built-in Bluetooth, plugged in a USB Bluetooth dongle (TP-Link UB400), and the link quality and the range were excellent.

I don't know what Bluetooth card your laptop has. For Intel AX201 I was able to find a thread about low Bluetooth range in Linux, and it seems that is a driver issue: https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-Wi-Fi6-AX201-160-MHz-Bluetooth-range-too-small-and/m-p/1284590